# How to switch between hide and view password in ios?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitextfield

Is there a clever way to let the user switch between hide and view password in an ios/iphone UITextField where the user can enter a password and would have the option of either hide it or view it.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Simply setting

```
.secureTextEntry = YES
```

wont work I think due to a bug (or a feature), if the textField has focus.

Use something like this to make it work also if the textField is currently firstResponder

```
-(void) toggleTextFieldSecureEntry: (UITextField*) textField {
    BOOL isFirstResponder = textField.isFirstResponder; //store whether textfield is firstResponder

    if (isFirstResponder) [textField resignFirstResponder]; //resign first responder if needed, so that setting the attribute to YES works
    textField.secureTextEntry = !textField.secureTextEntry; //change the secureText attribute to opposite
    if (isFirstResponder) [self.textField becomeFirstResponder]; //give the field focus again, if it was first responder initially
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
- (IBAction)ShowPass:(UIButton *)sender {
    if (self.password.secureTextEntry == YES) {
        [self.showPass setTitle:@"HIDE" forState:(UIControlStateNormal)];
        self.password.secureTextEntry = NO;   
    }else{
        [self.showPass setTitle:@"SHOW" forState:(UIControlStateNormal)];
        self.password.secureTextEntry = YES;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Mario's answer works fine and helped me a lot.

But if you use **custom font** in a text field, once you change from secure entry to plain text, the text field's text will be drawn with wrong (not custom) font until user inputs another character.

With a little hack I was able to fix this issue by simulating that character input from code.

This modified Mario's code should work for fields with custom fonts:

```
- (void)toggleTextFieldSecureEntry:(UITextField *)textField {
    BOOL isFirstResponder = textField.isFirstResponder;

    if (isFirstResponder) {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
    }

    textField.secureTextEntry = !textField.secureTextEntry;

    if (isFirstResponder) {
        [textField becomeFirstResponder];
    }

    // When using custom font and changing from secure entry to plain text, the text is initially drawn with wrong font
    // until a next character is input by user. This hack fixes the font immediatelly (simulate add and delete character)
    if (!textField.isSecureTextEntry) {
        [textField insertText:@"x"];
        [textField deleteBackward];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `secureTextEntry` property of `UITextField`. When you want to hide (show dot for each character) you can use `yourTextField.secureTextEntry=YES;`
And when you want to show password use `yourTextField.secureTextEntry=NO;`

Answer (score 1):

For Swift, only the assignment values change from YES/NO to true/false boolean values.

```
password.secureTextEntry = true //Visible
password.secureTextEntry = false //InVisible
```